# Corrupted file and tree in git

Tags: git

I just came back to a repo I haven't touched in a couple of months and it's giving me strange issues.

Here are the results of a number of actions:

```
>>> git status
[Works as expected] On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  deleted:    app/views/steps/_self_service_code.html.erb
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

>>> git fsck --name-objects
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (11080/11080), done.
broken link from    tree 13f6a8bd586b1d5a80a3e67610fc1103fdd827ad (HEAD@{1595970321}^:app/)
              to    tree 9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb (HEAD@{1595970321}^:app/views/)
missing tree 9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb (HEAD@{1595970321}^:app/views/)
missing blob 9241fc61b7d8ede2f9c1081d97db7f4ae2dd81a7 (:app/views/steps/_self_service_code.html.erb)
...

>>> git restore app/views/steps/_self_service_code.html.erb
error: unable to read sha1 file of app/views/steps/_self_service_code.html.erb (9241fc61b7d8ede2f9c1081d97db7f4ae2dd81a7)

>>> git log --raw --all --full-history | grep 9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb
fatal: unable to read tree 9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb

>>> git log --raw --all --full-history | grep 9241fc61b7d8ede2f9c1081d97db7f4ae2dd81a7
fatal: unable to read tree 9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb
```

I've tried everything I've read about online, including pulling from a Heroku repo and running 'First Aid' on my disk (it's a mac recently upgraded to Catalina from High Sierra). Nothing has fixed these issues so far.

Git version 2.28.0.

Comment: Did you try re-cloning the repository (instead of pulling as you stated)?

Comment: Is this an added worktree (from `git worktree add`)? Did you have Git 2.14 or earlier installed for a while, while using it? I've seen the pre-Git-2.15 bug in action here. Separately: `HEAD@{1595970321}`: that number in braces seems ridiculously huge; just how big is this HEAD reflog?

Comment: @torek It's not an added worktree - the repo has been one since the beginning. I was running an earlier version (not sure what version it was) for most of the time developing this repo.

Comment: @DarekKay I'll try cloning the repo, thanks.

Comment: @DarekKay Cloning the app does work but I lose all my stashes and branches - it's not really a workable solution as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue. I've created a new repository and ran `git ls-tree master`:

```
$ git ls-tree master
100644 blob 5cca282c0449f01cf317c3b4b7ed9f7d65125095    file-31e422aa.txt
100644 blob 03a9272a34f3085006cab8d7f1d6a45225a95a75    file-981ec394.txt
100644 blob 12c194b0694b456102f3ceaec027606b3b0b3edd    file-bf32de9c.txt
100644 blob 45aa64b2dfa1d0647be0d776c810eb493e882b23    file-f46b47e4.txt
040000 tree e560d2adfdbb678d625ca5de6f20abbc929f7092    moo
```

I deleted the file `.git/objects/e5/60d2adfdbb678d625ca5de6f20abbc929f7092` and ran the same command as you did:

```
$ git fsck --name-objects
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: e560d2adfdbb678d625ca5de6f20abbc929f7092: invalid sha1 pointer in cache-tree
broken link from    tree d0f8939f8d20cf252c1dd584526bcc6d7c3090e8 (:)
              to    tree e560d2adfdbb678d625ca5de6f20abbc929f7092 (:moo/)
missing tree e560d2adfdbb678d625ca5de6f20abbc929f7092 (:moo/)
```

As cloning the project solves your issue, it seems that the mentioned git objects are missing/corrupt in your `.git/objects` folder.

**Option 1**: Move your branches/stashes to your cloned repository.

**Option 2**: Move the broken git objects from your cloned repository into your broken repository.

Option 2 should work just fine. You can either move only the two objects mentioned in your CLI output or just copy&paste the entire `.git/objects` folder and *merge* (not overwrite!) it with your broken repository's `.git/objects` content. In any way, I suggest creating a full copy of your current broken repository before you attempt to solve the issue.

Note: be aware of the folder structure of your `.git/objects` folder. It contains two-char folders, where the two characters stand for the beginning of your object hash. So for example, your broken `9916bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb` tree will be in `.git/objects/99/16bab22f21c3e8d77a0c4bb2e633ec26e45edb` of your cloned repository (and missing or corrupt in your broken repository).

Comment: It took a little more work because the Heroku repo didn't include the .git/objects files. Instead, I used Time Machine to go back to a version that had those files and selectively moved them into a copy of the latest repo. This seems to have worked. Thank you very much for your help Derek! +1